# List.Sort() method places single digit last however non single digits are placed first python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

In the following code I run the sort method and it works perfectly except for one single problem. Post sort the third digit of the compute, if a single digit will be placed in the bottom

```
   linesAtTime = [['compute-1-1-14', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.7000000000e+01'],
    ['compute-1-1-14', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.5903333333e+01'],
    ['compute-1-5-26', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.4116666667e+01'],
    ['compute-1-5-26', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.3900000000e+01'],
    ['compute-2-18-17', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.6116666667e+01'],
    ['compute-2-18-17', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.6300000000e+01'],
    ['compute-1-6-17', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', 'NaN'],
    ['compute-1-6-17', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', 'NaN'],
    ['compute-1-1-7', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.1000000000e+01'],
    ['compute-1-1-7', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.0301666667e+01'],
    ['compute-1-2-33', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.9000000000e+01'],
    ['compute-1-2-33', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.8796666667e+01'],
    ['compute-1-8-19', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.2883333333e+01'],
    ['compute-1-8-19', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.2200000000e+01'],
    ['compute-1-5-15', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.3000000000e+01'],
    ['compute-1-5-15', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.3601666667e+01'],
    ['compute-1-1-12', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.0883333333e+01'],
    ['compute-1-1-12', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.0001666667e+01'],
    ]

    for i in linesAtTime:
        print(i)

    linesAtTime.sort()
    print()
    print()
    print()
    for i in linesAtTime:
        print(i)
```

Part of the example output looks like this

```
['compute-1-1-12', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.0001666667e+01']
['compute-1-1-12', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.0883333333e+01']
['compute-1-1-14', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.5903333333e+01']
['compute-1-1-14', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '6.7000000000e+01']
['compute-1-1-7', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.0301666667e+01']
['compute-1-1-7', '2019-09-04', '09:10:00', 'CDT', '7.1000000000e+01']
```

However the subarrays with the compute number 'compute-1-1-7' should be first, not last. I don't understand why this is. Is this something wrong with the built in function? Does anyone have a fix for it?